# quotation in reStructuredText/Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to put a quotation into a new block, in a reStructuredText document. What is the canonical way to do that? I see "quoted literal blocks" [here](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#quoted-literal-blocks), but at least the GitHub renderer doesn't do anything special with them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include an example of the literal block and how it is being rendered in github.

Comment: GitHub his limited rendering of reST. This might be one of the things that it does not render.

Comment: rST comes with standard syntax for [block quotes](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#block-quotes). Is there anything missing?